# mod_rewrite (router) в Code-igniter

Tags: mod_rewrite, php

Всем привет. Решил реализовать на сайте возможность распознания юзеров по более коротким адресным строкам.

Как есть сейчас:

```
http://site.ru/users/id/username
```

В базе данных имеется так же строка username (Как раз для распознания пользователя по нику).

Как хочу сделать:

```
http://site.ru/username
```

Первое, что попробовал, прописал в конфиге code-igniter в роуте:

```
$route['(:anu)'] = 'users/id/$1';
```

Теперь же, если перейти по любой ссылке, например адреса /test - он будет пытаться открыть юзера, а не страницу. Как выяснилось, ограничивать количество в роутерах нельзя.

Решил использовать mode_rewrite (в котором не разбираюсь), как я знаю там, мо-моему, можно ограничить на количество букв.

Например:

После первого слеша "/" считать количество букв, если оно больше 6 букв, то считать за юзера, если меньше 6 считать за страницу.

```
http://site.ru/test - страница
http://site.ru/usertest - пользователь.
```

Как можно реализовать такую задачу, если вообще возможно. Спасибо.

Comment: А разве вы не можете после получения в контроллере имени (проверка длины) ->  отправлять его другому контроллеру?

Comment: @Dex, Вы имеете ввиду создать дополнительный контроллер, на который роутер должен ссылаться, а уже в контроллере проверять количество символов и через контроллер правильно менять роутер? Впрочем, не плохая идея, можно попробовать. А если через mod_rewrite, то как это будет выглядеть?

Comment: mod_rewrite не подскажу, к сожалению

Comment: Суть в том, что распознавание модуля и юзера должно быть! У Вас зерегистрируется юзер под именем catalog или news, понимаете что при этом будет конфликт? По этому прще всего разделять юзеров как /u/username!


Я уже писал где-то на ХэшКоде что рядовому юзеру пофик как выглядит ссылка, я вроде и не рядовой - но и мне пофик!) По этому системно распределяйте ограничения между модулями и прочим!

Comment: Как раз все модули (функции сайта, разделы) у меня до 6 символов.
Например: http://site.ru/edit и т.д. А я хочу дать возможность пользователям делать имя от 6 символов. По-моему, конфликтов не должно быть.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Не очень я долго работал с CodeIgniter, но там же можно использовать регулярные выражения в маршрутизации. Что-то вроде этого должно помочь:

```
$route['([a-z0-9_-]{7,})'] = 'users/id/$1'; // разрешенные символы исправьте на свои
```

[Русская документация по CI :: Маршрутизация](http://code-igniter.ru/user_guide/general/routing.html).

Comment: http://cidocs.ru/ - Руководство пользователя CodeIgniter 2.1.0 на русском языке.

Comment: Действительно, у вас свежее, хотя регулярные выражения никуда не исчезли и не изменились.